# While Inserting the data in MySQL getting error for the update column in Symfony2.4, Doctrine, PHP

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Problem - I want to save the data that is submitted from the form, when i am saving it to MySQL getting error as -

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'updated' cannot be null
```

But I have given the update column the default value as 0000-00-00 00:00:00 , by default it must take the default value.

I am using the "prepersist" technique to add the code before saving it to MySQL.

The following is my "prepersist" code snippet from which the above error got generated-

```
public function setBeforeInsertData() {
    $this->added    =   new \DateTime();
}
```

I have used the following code to overcome the error just for the time being I know that its a wrong approach.

```
public function setBeforeInsertData() {
    $this->added    =   new \DateTime();
    $this->updated  =   new \DateTime();
}
```

The following is the Entity for the respective table -

```
<?php

namespace Skerp\InventoryBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * InventoryLocation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="inventory_location")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class InventoryLocation
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="locName", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $locname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address1", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address2", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address2;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="address3", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address3;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="zipCode", type="string", length=5, nullable=false)
     */
    private $zipcode;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="state", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=40, nullable=false)
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fax", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $fax;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=40, nullable=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="contactNo", type="string", length=20, nullable=false)
     */
    private $contactno;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="addedBy", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $addedby;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="added", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $added;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inventLocId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $inventlocid;



    /**
     * Set locname
     *
     * @param string $locname
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setLocname($locname)
    {
        $this->locname = $locname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get locname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLocname()
    {
        return $this->locname;
    }

    /**
     * Set address1
     *
     * @param string $address1
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAddress1($address1)
    {
        $this->address1 = $address1;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address1
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddress1()
    {
        return $this->address1;
    }

    /**
     * Set address2
     *
     * @param string $address2
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAddress2($address2)
    {
        $this->address2 = $address2;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address2
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddress2()
    {
        return $this->address2;
    }

    /**
     * Set address3
     *
     * @param string $address3
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAddress3($address3)
    {
        $this->address3 = $address3;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address3
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddress3()
    {
        return $this->address3;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set zipcode
     *
     * @param string $zipcode
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setZipcode($zipcode)
    {
        $this->zipcode = $zipcode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zipcode
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getZipcode()
    {
        return $this->zipcode;
    }

    /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setState($state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * Set country
     *
     * @param string $country
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get country
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * Set telephone
     *
     * @param string $telephone
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setTelephone($telephone)
    {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTelephone()
    {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * Set fax
     *
     * @param string $fax
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setFax($fax)
    {
        $this->fax = $fax;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fax
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFax()
    {
        return $this->fax;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set contactno
     *
     * @param string $contactno
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setContactno($contactno)
    {
        $this->contactno = $contactno;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get contactno
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getContactno()
    {
        return $this->contactno;
    }

    /**
     * Set addedby
     *
     * @param string $addedby
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAddedby($addedby)
    {
        $this->addedby = $addedby;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get addedby
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAddedby()
    {
        return $this->addedby;
    }

    /**
     * Set added
     *
     * @param \DateTime $added
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setAdded($added)
    {
        $this->added = $added;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get added
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getAdded()
    {
        return $this->added;
    }

    /**
     * Set updated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updated
     * @return InventoryLocation
     */
    public function setUpdated($updated)
    {
        $this->updated = $updated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updated
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    /**
     * Get inventlocid
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getInventlocid()
    {
        return $this->inventlocid;
    }
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    */
    public function setBeforeInsertData() {
        $this->added    =   new \DateTime();
        //$this->updated  =   new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show you entity i guess you have mismatched column names and properties of entity

Comment: The entities are matching perfectly...

Comment: Are you sure that you used proper annotations?

Comment: @bartek Just a sec I will update question with the Entity Code

Comment: @bartek is there anything that i need to modify in the annotations

Comment: When such simple lifecycle events are the issue I often rely on `__construct` to do all the stuff. After all, `$em->persist` occurs only once and those fields will be overwritten with current values as soon as you load the data ;)

Comment: @user1696621 Actually it is mismatched; on the functions you set `$this->added_on` and `$this->updated_on` whereas in your entity you have `$added` and `$updated`

Answer (score 0):

Your entity class should have following annotation: `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()`. Your methods should have `@ORM\PrePersist` annotation. More info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: Even after adding the respective annotations its giving the same error as - "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'updated' cannot be null ". Is there any other way so that the updated column will get the default value as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: Would you please be so kind and update your question by pasting FULL entity class including ALL necessary annotations? BTW have you tried ./app/console c:c after doing changes?

Comment: ya I have even tried "php app/console cache:clear" but facing the same issue...just a sec i wil update my Entity Code

Comment: I might be wrong, but commented code won't work. - //$this->updated  =   new \DateTime();

Comment: @bartek: Legend says it does not :)

Comment: Ya that wont work out....thats why i have commented it out....for the time being i am using it till i get the solution from you guys....waiting for the one :)

Comment: Can you try something simple like throwing an Exception inside this PrePersist() method to see if it is actually executed?